# No working function ng-class with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I cannot run function in the ng-class. I've copied what I've been doing, could you look for the error? What I want to do is to put the bold style on the element selected with a button. The Angular version is 1.3.4. Comment 'index' never shows in the console.

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(numsteps) track by $index" 
    ng-class="isActive($index) ">
    {{$index + 1}}
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.it = 0;

$scope.isActive = function(index) {
    console.log('index');
    if ($scope.it === index) {
        return "bold";
    }
};

$scope.next = function () {                
    $scope.it = $scope.it < $scope.dataNumsteps
        ? $scope.it + 1
        : $scope.dataNumsteps;

    console.log($scope.it);
};

$scope.after = function () {                
    $scope.it = $scope.it > 1 ? $scope.it - 1 : 1
    console.log($scope.it);
};
```

Comment: Try a more semantic usage of ng-class: `ng-class="{bold: it === $index}"`

Comment: William B It is the first solution I tried but not working

Comment: It works with value comparator `==`, though the types are the same Angular must be doing something unexpected when comparing them. @ram1993, quotes dont matter if there's no spaces or dashes in the class name. http://jsfiddle.net/qopfm2vw/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think your actual problem is the space in your ng-class attribute: `ng-class="isActive($index) "`

When removed, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7pn2un39/

Comment: Not found. Not output from console the message 'index'. so it does not enter the function

Comment: What are you talking about? This example works. See the bold class on the first `li`: `class="ng-scope ng-binding bold"`

Comment: Look console.log('index'). The message no output from console... But in you example yes

Comment: Post a working code sample if you want further troubleshooting help. You can see my example works, all I did was remove the space from your ng-class

Comment: A trailing space in ng-class is not a problem. Your example works even with a space at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/h6ucayer/

Comment: The problem was that it was different $ scope. I've already solved, thanks.